# Return list of columns in Dataframe that have a specific value as new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of columns  that have values of either "Yes" or "No" in them. I am hoping to create a function that adds an additional column listing the columns for a specific row that are equal to "Yes". If they are all equal to "No" it would simply return nothing.

Example

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 New Column 
Yes      No       No       Yes      No       Column 1, Column 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of your column names are strings:

```
df['New Column'] = df.apply(lambda row: ', '.join(row.index[row == 'Yes']), axis=1)
```

If you have non-string column names (e.g. an integer) you can do essentially the same thing, but cast the type to string first:

```
df['New Column'] = df.apply(lambda row: ', '.join(row.index.astype(str)[row == 'Yes']), axis=1)
```

For each row, I'm using Boolean indexing on the row's index (i.e. the columns) to only select the locations that are `'Yes'`.  Then I'm simply doing a string join on all of the `'Yes'` column names.

Sample Output (with two additional sample rows):

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5          New Column
0      Yes       No       No      Yes       No  Column 1, Column 4
1       No       No       No       No       No                    
2       No      Yes       No       No       No            Column 2
```

Comment: Thanks root! This solved it and allowed the rows with all "no"s to be left blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
df['New'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x == 'Yes'].tolist(), axis=1)

df
```

[image]